# New, uneven LVP flooring in fixed-up 1960s home

Tags: floor, subfloor, vinyl-flooring, vinyl

My family moved into our first home a few days ago, originally built in the 60s, and which was fixed up by a previous investor.

We have LVP flooring in the living/kitchen areas, but the flooring seems to be uneven, and we can feel the planks/tiles/strips move under our feet. Some of the joints (?) between adjacent tiles are also uneven -- you can see in this image how I press one tile down with simply a couple of fingers, such that it sinks a bit below.

[image: pressing down on a plank]

The question on my mind is basically, how serious is this issue? Should we be considering inspections, repairs, or (in the worst case) redoing the entire flooring?

My first worry that our flooring is simply not waterproof any more (water can leak into the crawl space etc.).

Second, I wonder if these flooring issues are hiding even bigger issues in the subflooring.

The "flexible" flooring is also not very nice to walk on, around the house ... But I guess we can get used to it if it's not going to cause major issues in the medium-long term (~5 years, perhaps).

Comment: @crip659: are you recommending we take off the pieces and potentially flatten the subfloor in the worst affected areas?

Comment: Comment answers flagged. Both have issues. Removing a floor often requires removing related trim, so it's not "as easy". Waterproofness absolutely _does_ depend on stable joints.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the product is, or whether it even _is_ considered waterproof?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the product in our home: https://www.engineeredfloors.com/new-standard-plus/ . They say "Waterproof Warranty: Lifetime" - I assume a correct installation must be waterproof.

Comment: There's "waterproof" as in the floor *as a system* won't let water through to the subfloor, and there's "waterproof" as in each plank will be undamaged if soaked in water.  YMMV in both conditions, depending on the brand/model of LVP.

Answer (score 3):

There may be an issue under the LVP with the subfloor or the flooring structure, however there is no way of knowing without getting under the floor and looking, ( basement, crawlspace).

If the only issue you have is the LVP has a few soft areas and the seams are not tight there is nothing to suggest that a more serious issue is present.

LVP likes to be installed on a perfectly flat surface. Many believe this means level, but it's the flatness that is an issue.  When the LVP has a slight void under it, it will flex under foot. This can be temporary and the flooring will acclimate to a degree and relax to that void. In a few weeks that void will not be felt.

The seams not being tight is a separate issue. Yes they lose their waterproof seal when not tight. In a bathroom or the kitchen by the sink can be a possible  problem.  This is more likely from a poor installation rather than serious issues under the flooring.

The proper fix would be to remove the baseboard or 1/4 round closest to the seam at the short side of the board. Then tapping the line of flooring with a [Pull Bar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085Y3LJGR) until the seam is tight. Reinstall the 1/4 round or baseboard.
If the seam cannot be made tight, a little latex caulk of matching color can be applied to seal the seam. Push the caulk deep into the seam and wipe the surface with a damp sponge.  It will help if water is spilled. In the event of a flood, it really won't matter

All in all the most likely issue you have is a sloppy installation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! About the caulking solution for seams ... Since the panels are flexing under our feet, this is probably causing the seams to move against each other, which might mean that any caulk we apply won't be stable ... right?

Comment: I generally agree, though the fact that adjacent planks can move with respect to each other seems to indicate damage. They should be locked together in a snug tongue-and-groove arrangement. There may be splitting of the plank.

Comment: you can do the inject epoxy under the tiles that flex trick - search youtube

Comment: LVP cannot split without a great amount of force.  It has to be a bend and a counter bend in the opposite direction. Multiple times. Then the core splits and the surface area just stretches.